# Error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html using Flask in python. Simple use of Flask for beginner application

Tags: flask

### Error: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound - Flask can't find index.html

**Description:**
I'm trying to build a simple web app with Flask, but I encountered an error when attempting to render the index.html template. I'm getting the following error message:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
raise TemplateNotFound(template)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. I've created a Python file (app.py) with Flask code and placed it in the "templates" directory alongside the index.html file.
2. When running the app.py with the IDLE python, I get the above error.

**Code:**

```py
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/Username/Desktop/templates')
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    name = request.form['name']
    age = request.form['age']
    # Here to save the date in anyway
    return f'Hello {name}, you are {age}!'


# the html code named index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My first website</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome in my first website</h1>
<p>Compila i dati:</p>
<form method="POST" action="/submit">
<label for="name">Nome:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
<br>
<label for="age">Età:</label>
<input type="number" id="age" name="age" required>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>


Expected Result:
I expected the Flask app to render the index.html template without any errors.

Attempts Made:

I've verified that the index.html file is located in the same "templates" directory as the app.py file.
I've tried specifying the full path in render_template, but the error persists.
Environment:
Operating System: Windows 10
Python Version: 3.11

Thank you in advance!!
```

Comment: `os.chdir('C:/Users/Username/Desktop/templates')` looks very strange. Normally you don't have to change the folder. Flask looks already for the templates directory in the module's root path, see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates for more information. The template folder should not have application code (python code) in it, only the files to render (html, powered by jinja). You don't need to customize your template folder, then: (`app = Flask(__name__)`). If you do so, ensure that the path to templates folder relative from module/package root is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should save **index.html** as **templates/index.html**.

Modify the code as shown below.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def saveFormData():
    name = request.form['name']
    age = request.form['age']

    # One may use a Python dict to retrieve the data.

    data = request.form.to_dict()

    return ('Hello ' + name + ' you are ' + age)
```

Save the code above as hello.py.

To execute it, you can use the command below.

```
FLASK_APP=hello.py flask --debug run
```

The complete directory structure should be as follows.

```
.
├── hello.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your replay.
I tried your proposal, but I again get the same error. 
The path of the both file are: Desktop/templates. 
In the directory "templates" there are both hello.py and index.html. It is as if the index.html file did not exist.
I don't understand why doesn't work. When I execute the file hello.py from cdm appears
Serving Flask app 'hello.py'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
but if I go to the adress I get that error

Comment: In the main directory there should be only hello.py. In the templates directory there should be only index.html.

Comment: The answer has been updated, please review it again.